# state.divsion index in R

Tags: r, indexing, state

I'm asked to use the state.x77 data set and find the minimum income for each division defined by state.division and then use the state.name to find the name of the state that is in New England that has the minimum income.  I'm getting some weird answers.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
x <- tapply(state.x77$Income, state.division, min)
x
New England    Middle Atlantic     South Atlantic East South Central 
          3694               4449               3617               3098 
West South Central East North Central West North Central           Mountain 
          3378               4458               4167               3601 
       Pacific 
          4660 
x1 <- tapply(state.x77$Income, state.name[state.division], min)
x1
Alabama      Alaska     Arizona    Arkansas  California    Colorado 
   3694        4449        3617        3098        3378        4458 
Connecticut    Delaware     Florida 
   4167        3601        4660
```

Comment: Is this your homework? And if so, did your teacher just teach you about dplyr's groupby and filter?

Comment: I have not used those as much.  I think that we are required to use state.division and state.name.  Otherwise, I think that we are open to whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally tend to go straight for `dplyr`, where you could use either

```
library(dplyr)
result <- state.x77 %>% 
    group_by(state.division) %>%
    filter(Income == min(Income))
```

if you want to preserve all minimum value rows (as in, if there are two minimums) or

```
state.x77 %>% 
    group_by(state.division) %>%
    slice(which.min(Income))
```

if you want only one minimum value row.

If you want to only use the base package, you could try using `ave()` with `min`:

```
state.x77[state.x77$Distance == ave(state.x77$Income, state.x77$state.division, FUN = min), ]
```